# Heroku Postgres professional tier database plan shows "no backup?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

We have a premium 2 plan which is in staging right now. When I use the command `heroku pg:backups --app APPNAME`, it shows

> no backup capture one with heroku pg:backups:capture

The documentation says continuous protection is available with professional tier database plan which we have but still not able to see any backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku's "continuous protection" for PostgreSQL [refers to write ahead log (WAL) files being written to external storage](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-data-safety-and-continuous-protection#physical-backups-on-heroku-postgres). This is different from the logical PGBackups service.

You can roll your database back to an earlier state from WAL files [by creating a new Postgres database with `heroku addons:create` using the `--rollback` option](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-rollback). Run

```
heroku pg:info --app APPNAME
```

to see if this is available for your database. You should see a `Rollback` value.

It is probably also a good idea to [schedule regular logical backups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#scheduling-backups) using PGBackup, e.g. via

```
heroku pg:backups:schedule DATABASE_URL --at '02:00 America/Los_Angeles' --app APPNAME
```